# set max-memory parameter in pyspark mllib random forest

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, random-forest

I use `RandomForest` MLlib PySpark 2.3. How can I set the `MaxMemoryInMb`? As far as I know this method is not implemented in PySpark 2.3.

I ask because I got following warning in my experiment:

```
WARN RandomForest: Tree learning is using approximately 724037600 
bytes per iteration, which exceeds requested limit
maxMemoryUsage=268435456. This allows splitting 1 nodes in this iteration.
```

Comment: Please include the code also, and put the output in a code box, not bold font.

Comment: my data includes 5000000 instances. the output of my code doesn't get Error, but this WARN causes to sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pypark.ml` where [`setMaxMemoryInMB`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassifier.setMaxMemoryInMB)

> **setMaxMemoryInMB**(value)
>     Sets the value of **maxMemoryInMB**.

and [`maxMemoryInMB` parameter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassifier)

> class pyspark.ml.classification.**DecisionTreeClassifier**(self, ...,  maxMemoryInMB=256, ...)

are present in PySpark since initial release in Spark 1.4 and where `setMaxMemoryInMB` belongs.

`pyspark.mllib` is frozen (no new features will be added) and internally uses `pyspark.ml.`